# Is it valid if I use HTTP method POST for fetching data?

Tags: rest, http, post, get, query-string

What I know that the HTTP method GET is for fetching/searching data and POST is for create/insert data.

But what if there is a case that I want to search data but the parameters (key-value pairs) are so many or big that there is possibility it will go over the query string limit for the GET method.

In this case, if I use POST for searching data, is it valid in the REST or HTTP specification?

Comment: This is a limitation of GET (that still affects IE with it's 2k limit). If POST *must* be used to overcome this (or other hacks like cookie-stuffing) then POST *must* be used .. however, having so much search data might indicate that other changes could be made. Might it be sufficient to simply encode/reduce the search data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its perfectly valid in the scenarios where you have lot many number of variable parameters.